# Can a ScopedValue be applied to "the current" StructuredTaskScope without creating a new task?

Tags: java, java-21, structured-concurrency

I'm investigating using `ScopedValue` and `StructuredTaskScope` to replace usage of Google's gRPC context.

Both systems are nicely immutable, lightweight and support nested scopes, but I think gRPC context does something I need which might not be available via ScopedValue (which would be a real shame if true).

In various frameworks, I might need to enable debugging on a per-request basis, turning on additional logging if a request matches some criteria. However my code is never in a position to wrap some function in order to nest it in a new task, it's simply code which gets called and must exit before the request is handled. In pseudo-code:

```java
// Assume one handler per request.
class MyHandler implements SomeFrameworkCallbackApi {
    MyCloseable resetDebug = null;

    @Override
    void beforeRequest(RequestHeaders req, ConfigInfo info) {
        if (info.addLogging() && shouldDebug(req)) {
            Context newGrpcContext = Context.current().withValue(DEBUG_LEVEL, Level.FINE);
            Context prev = newGrpcContext.attach();
            resetDebug = () -> newGrpcContext.detach(prev);
        }
    }

    @Override
    void afterRequest(...) {
        if (resetDebug != null) {
            // Fails if not called in strict nesting order.
            resetDebug.close();
        }
    }
}
```

This lets me have scoped variables even in situations where I am not able to modify code which can wrap the task directly.

From looking at the APIs for `ScopedValue` and `StructuredTaskScope` it looks like the only way to run code with a `ScopedValue` installed is to call a method such as `run()`, which forces a nesting call to the task at that point (which is not possible in many frameworks).

I had tried:

```java
resetDebug = ScopedValue.getWhere(DEBUG_LEVEL, Level.FINE, StructuredTaskScope::new)::close;
```

But this results in `java.util.concurrent.StructureViolationException` (not unexpectedly).

So my question is, is there any other way to use `ScopedValue` (with or without `StructuredTaskScope`) which might achieve what I'm after, or do I need to stay with gRPC context?

Comment: I am not sure if I could infer your question correctly, but are you looking for a completion handler for a structured scope? Maybe something of `class RequestScope<T> extends StructuredTaskScope<T> implements SomeFrameworkCallbackApi` sort?

Comment: No, it's not about completion, it's about being able to add a new scoped value, unrelated to any specific framework, in a way that doesn't require directly wrapping the affected code (since I have to access to the code that's about to be executed, only hooks that are called before and after).

Comment: No, you can not do that, as it would defeat the entire purpose of having a *scoped* value. However, there’s also no need to do that, when you already have hooks executed before and after the operation, together with an instance bound to the operation which can hold the necessary state during the operation. The purpose of `ScopeValue` is to help out when you don’t have that.

Comment: I'm not sure that argument always holds. There are situations in which (just as for ThreadLocal / ScopedValue) you would want to lookup a value (by key) from library code which doesn't know it's running in some specific framework. My example is for debug log levels, which cross-cut into libraries and other non-framework, non-DI system aware code. The value *is* still scoped by the way, it's just not scoped by using the call stack directly.

Comment: Well, yes, Kenobi would say it’s scoped “from a certain point of view”. It’s just not scoped in the way, `ScopedValue` is scoped. Letting definitions aside, there still is nothing you could gain by shoehorning `ScopedValue` into your scenario, even if it worked. The code to use it still has to know it to query the actual value. If you code can query a scoped value, it can also query an ordinary variable which you can set in `beforeRequest` and reset in `afterRequest`. It would be a different picture if you had a framework embracing the concept of structured concurrency/ scoped values…

Comment: The code a library that's independent of frameworks won't easily have access to the per-request state. I can't know which environment the library would be used in, so have no nice way to tunnel the value through other than something like a ThreadLocal or (since it's more efficient) a ScopedValue.
I'm not saying this is great in a lot of cases, but for things like enabling debugging in a non-intrusive way, it's important to not require users to refactor all their code just to start using a library.

Comment: As far as I can recognize, the code example in your question is the application code whose methods are to be invoked by some framework. Now you’re talking about developing a library where the other code would be the application code. It’s pointless to meander through different scenarios. When all you want to hear is “yes, there are scenarios where `ScopedValue` is useful”, there you go. Nobody denied that. The scenario as posted in the question, however, is not such scenario.

Comment: I am not meandering, you just didn't understand the question. Since you're not providing useful information and don't seem to know the answer one way or another (instead you are turning this into some expression of your personal thoughts about scoped values) I'm just going to ignore you.

Comment: @David This is simply not how scoped values work, by design.  What you seem to want is the unrestricted mutability of `ThreadLocal`, but with the improved performance of `ScopedValue`.  But `ScopedValue` derives its benefits from the constraints you don't seem to like.

Comment: Thank you, that's exactly the concise, straightforward answer I was after. I'll stick to gRPC context (and similar APIs) for what I'm doing, since I cannot require my library's users to be in a situation where `ScopedValue` would be usable.

Answer (score 1):

From Brian Goetz:

""This is simply not how scoped values work, by design. What you seem to want is the unrestricted mutability of ThreadLocal, but with the improved performance of ScopedValue. But ScopedValue derives its benefits from the constraints you don't seem to like.""

So the answer is simply that `ScopedValue` can only be used in situations where scoping is achieved by wrapping code directly, rather than the use of some setup/teardown callbacks which occur before/after code is run.

This means that `ScopedValue` cannot be general replacement for existing `ThreadLocal`-based context libraries (e.g. `gRPC Context` or `Open Telemetry contexts`).

In my situation (setting up scoped values for a library which can be called from many flavours of framework), I simply don't have the freedom to require that users refactor their code, which sits between the framework and my library, to implement all their scoping via the direct wrapping of code.

If your need is similar to mine, then `gRPC Context` provides the additional functionality to allow scoping via the use of a returned `Closeable` to manage things (e.g. managing scopes via `try-with-resources`).